# Unarchive a file into specific directory

Tags: command-line, tar

Running the command, I end up with the file being in `/home/user/Documents/home/user/Documents/`.

```
tar -xzvf /tmp/file.tar.gz -C /home/user/Documents/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because you have use absolute paths while creating the archive, and as you are using `-C` to do `chdir(2)` before unarchiving, you will get the absolute paths starting from where you have `chdir(2)`-ed.

Now, you have two options if you want to use `-C`:

- Use relative paths while creating the archive, and then you can use `-C` like you have used while unarchiving:

  ```
  tar -xzvf /tmp/file.tar.gz -C /home/user/Documents/
  ```

  pick the destination carefully to make sure it does not have the possibility of overwriting anything existing.
- Change the directory to `/`, and use the absolute paths while archiving, and again of course choose the `chdir(2)` path very carefully in this case as this could replace any existing file:

  ```
   tar -xzvf /tmp/file.tar.gz -C /
  ```

  based on your example, this will put the file(s) in `/home/user/Documents/`.

Comment: Another option might be to use GNU tar's `--strip-components` option